# Geometry find the distance from the edge of a square to the rim of the largest possible circle inside that square

Tags: geometry

Math was never my strong suit. :)  Given a square canvas of arbitrary size measured in pixels, I draw the largest possible circle of width 1 inside that canvas. I then want to draw a rectangle (not necessarily square) centered inside the circle with the corners touching the circle.  So I need a formula to calculate the X and Y coordinates of the upper-left pixel for that inner rectangle given the diameter of the circle.  Or alternately, given an X number of pixels along the top and Y number of pixels along the left side of the canvas, I need a formula to find the X/Y coordinates of the vertically and horizontally matching point on the rim of that circle.  Thanks! :)

Answer (score -1):

Given that the sine rule applies, the length of the sides of a square inside the circle should be Len = (Dia / sin(90)) / 2, and the X and Y coordinates for the upper-left corner then would both be ((Dia - Len) div 2).  For a rectangle, inc/dec the X and Y equally.  In Delphi:

```
    procedure SquareInCircle(Dia: Integer; var P: TPoint; Padding: Integer = 0);
    //Given a circle of diameter Dia, find the X and Y of the
    //upper-left corner of a square with corners on the rim
    //of the circle.  Consider the diameter @ 45°, which forms
    //a right triangle from the square; the length of any side
    //of the square is the diameter / sin(90) / 2, and from that,
    //the X and Y of the upper-left are (dia - len) / 2.  Since
    //we're working in pixels, results are kept as integers.
    var
      L: Integer;
    begin
      L := Round((Dia / Sin(90)) / 2);
      P.X := ((Dia - L) div 2) + Padding;
      P.Y := P.X;
    end;

    procedure RectInCircle(Dia, Ofs: Integer; var P: TPoint; Padding: Integer = 0);
    //Ofs is the number of pixels to offset from square to rectangle.
    //If ofs is negative, the rectangle is taller than it is high;
    //if ofs is positive, the rectangle is wider than it is tall.
    //Ofs must be >= 0 and < (dia / 2).
    begin
      SquareInCircle(Dia, P, Padding);
      Dec(P.X, Ofs);
      Inc(P.Y, Ofs);
    end;
```

Comment: Wrong approaches,  completely incorrect code (just look at  `Sin(90)`). It is worth to formulate your question properly and show a picture

Comment: OK... but it works.  Or I should say, it returns appropriate results.  Please explain how it's wrong.

Comment: Did you mean that sin(90) is incorrect?  I have private functions that convert degrees to radians internally to simplify things.  Should have included that, sorry.

Comment: OK, now it is clear with radians/degrees. But `(Dia / Sin(90))/2 = Dia/2`... Perhaps I do not understand your problem without clear description and picture.

Comment: Further digging led me to my error.  On a square inside but touching the circle, to get the length of the square's sides = (Dia / 2) * Sqrt(2).  On a rectangle, I need to also know the angle of the corner of the dividing diameter to calc it accurately, but for my purposes, just inc/dec the pixels is sufficient.  I'm using this to determine the width/height of the area inside the circle in which I can safely print text without it potentially extending outside the circle.